# Deploy Ruby on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I am a noobie on programming I started to install Ruby with the go rails tutorial.

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10#rails
I reached the final stage but it didn't work,
so i made a .rb file with this text and try to run it on Terminal,didn't worked.

Any one know what I am supposed to do?

```
#### If you want to use SQLite (not recommended)
rails new myapp

#### If you want to use MySQL
rails new myapp -d mysql

#### If you want to use Postgres
# Note that this will expect a postgres user with the same username
# as your app, you may need to edit config/database.yml to match the
# user you created earlier
rails new myapp -d postgresql

# Move into the application directory
cd myapp

# If you setup MySQL or Postgres with a username/password, modify the
# config/database.yml file to contain the username/password that you specified

# Create the database
rake db:create

rails server

You can now visit http://localhost:3000 to view your new website!

Now that you've got your machine setup, it's time to start building some Rails applications.

If you received an error that said Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) then you need to update your config/database.yml file to match the database username and password.
We're sharing everything we know
about how to write great quality code

Join the GoRails mailing list to learn more about what great code looks like, why it is great, and how you can write great code yourself that you will enjoy working with.
```

Comment: Which part didn't work and what was the error message?

Comment: its was" rails new myapp" I just understand that i needed authorisation to configure index.html wich is located to var,ito run it,m looking for way to get the authorisation.

Comment: You don't want to run all of those commands, you wouldn't want to make the "new myapp" over and over.  Also, this wouldn't go in a .rb file, that's not for running shell commands.  Finally, you have text at the bottom after "rails server" that are also not proper commands.

More importantly, if you want help here, you need to tell us the exact commands you ran and the exact output/errors you got.